# Terraform - Objects in wrong order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt

I want to get host IPs out of two subnets in AWS using Terraform/Terragrunt and the cidrhost function.

For some reason, the subnets are being injected into cidrhost in the wrong order.

The remote state it's checking looks like this:

```
"firewall_subnets_cidr_blocks": {["10.0.0.96/28", "10.0.0.112/28"]}
```

The first subnet is in 1a and the second in 1b

And this is my code:

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "private" {
  count                = length(var.firewall_subnets) > 0 ? length(var.firewall_subnets) : 0
  subnet_id            = element(var.firewall_subnets, count.index)
  private_ip           = cidrhost(tolist(var.firewall_subnets_cidr_blocks)[count.index], 10)
  description          = "Private Interface"
  security_groups      = [aws_security_group.sg_firewall_private.id]
  source_dest_check    = false
}
```

Whenever I run it, it puts the first subnet into the second - the 1b -  interface and vice versa.

```
# aws_network_interface.private[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_network_interface" "private" {
      + description               = "Private Interface"
      + private_ip                = "10.0.0.122"

  # aws_network_interface.private[1] will be created
  + resource "aws_network_interface" "private" {
      + description               = "Private Interface"
      + private_ip                = "10.0.0.106"
```

It only happens on this interface script; management and public are identical and behaving as expected.

TF 1.1.9
TG 0.37.3

Comment: Plan output order is not necessarily apply order. If those do not have any dependencies, it's likely they will create concurrently.

Comment: As a side note, you should generally use `for_each` instead of count on TF > 0.11. Count still has some uses, but the newer `for_each` method is generally cleaner for most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging into the documentation I found this statement:

**For a new network interface, the same primary IP address is consistently selected from a given set of addresses, regardless of the order provided.**

This sorting happens before the list is passed to my functions resulting in the wrong IPs going to the wrong subnet/AZ.

To override this behaviour I've set `private_ip_list_enabled` to `true`.

Here's my working code:

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "private" {
  count = length(var.private_subnets) > 0 ?  length(var.private_subnets) : 0
  subnet_id               = element(var.private_subnets, count.index)
  private_ip_list_enabled = true
  private_ip_list         = tolist([cidrhost(element(var.private_subnets_cidr_blocks, count.index), 10)])
  description             = "Private Interface"
  source_dest_check       = false
}
```

**Victory is mine!**